# Laravel 9 Query Builder MS Access SQL Conversion

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I have this query for SQL accessing an old Access DB.  I need to convert it to use query builder. I don't need a model, just to be able to use QB to query the db.

```
sql = "SELECT tblSU.Site, tlkpSUDesc.ESR_SUcat, tlkpSUDesc.ESR_SUcatdisp, tlkpSUDesc.SUDesc, tlkpSUTyp.SUTyp, tblSU.SUNum"
sql = sql & " FROM tlkpSUTyp RIGHT JOIN (tlkpSUDesc RIGHT JOIN tblSU ON tlkpSUDesc.SUDescCode = tblSU.SUDescCode) ON tlkpSUTyp.SUTypCode = tblSU.SUTypCode"
sql = sql & " WHERE (((tblSU.Site)='" & request("Site") & "') AND ((tlkpSUDesc.ESR_SUcat)='" & request("Crit") & "') AND (Not (tblSU.SUTypCode)='GEN'))"
sql = sql & " ORDER BY tblSU.Site, tlkpSUDesc.ESR_SUcatdisp, tblSU.SUDescCode, CDbl(IIf(InStr([tblSU]![SUNum],'-'),Left([tblSU]![SUNum],Len([tblSU]![SUNum])-2),[tblSU]![SUNum]))"
```

Comment: I can get this using DB::select and it returns this:

```
array:1 [▼ // app/Http/Controllers/Study.php:45
  0 => {#288 ▼
    +"Site": "5MT10647"
    +"ESR_SUcat": "Kivas"
    +"ESR_SUcatdisp": 1
    +"SUDesc": "subterranean kiva"
    +"SUTyp": "Structure"
    +"SUNum": "102"
  }
]
```
But I cannot access it in my view using {{ $structure->ESR_SUcatdisp }} inside or outside a foreach.  This doesn't work either

{{ $structures['ESR_SUcatdisp'] }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DB::raw('your sql query')`;

Comment: So I did that and is just "Prints" the statement when I dump it.

```Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression {#285 ▼ // app/Http/Controllers/Study.php:51
  #value: """
    SELECT tblSU.Site, tlkpSUDesc.ESR_SUcat, tlkpSUDesc.ESR_SUcatdisp, tlkpSUDesc.SUDesc, tlkpSUTyp.SUTyp, tblSU.SUNum
                    FROM tlkpSUTyp...```

I added some more above,